Understanding How InteractiveServer Works in Blazor
I am trying to understand how InteractiveServer works in Blazor.
When using InteractiveServer, does it only re-render the variable currentCount to show the updated value, or does it re-render the entire page to reflect the updated currentCount?
Here is an example code snippet:
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

The documentation does not clearly explain how InteractiveServer updates or re-renders the changed value Microsoft InteractiveServer documentation..
Can someone clarify this behavior?
I have been reading the Microsoft InteractiveServer documentation on InteractiveServer to understand its behavior.
I excepted the InteractiveServer to either:

Only re-render the currentCount variable to reflect the updated count, or
Re-render the entire page to reflect the updated currentCount.

However, the Microsoft InteractiveServer documentation does not specify which behavior occurs, and I haven't been able to determine this from my own testing.


does it only re-render the variable currentCount to show the updated value, or does it re-render the entire page to reflect the updated currentCount?

It does both. Blazor uses a 'virtual DOM' and in a re-render that entire DOM is re-build against the existing one. With some optimizations, sub-components are re-rendered based on their parameters etc.
And then only the detected changes, in this example the currentCount, are updated in the actual (much slower) DOM.
It works the same for Blazor Wasm, and the virtual DOM concept is also used in for instance the React framework.
You should be aware of this virtual DOM when you combine Blazor with pure JS libraries. Avoid mutating for instance the same <div> with both.
